# Why does conversion of binary to decimal involve the number '8'?

Tags: ruby, binary, byte, binaries

I am looking at the solution for the following coding challenge on Coderbyte:

> Using the Ruby language, have the function `BinaryReversal(str)` take the `str` parameter being passed, which will be a positive integer, take its binary representation, reverse that string of bits, and then finally return the new reversed string in decimal form. For example: if `str` is `"47"` then the binary version of this integer is `00101111`. Your program should reverse this binary string which then becomes: `11110100` and then finally return the decimal version of this string, which is `244`.

The solution is:

```
def BinaryReversal(str, dig = 8)
  binary = str.to_i.to_s(2).reverse
  dig += 8 until dig >= binary.length
  binary += '0' until binary.length == dig
  binary.to_i(2)
end
```

I don't understand why the binary needs to have `0`s added onto it until it's length is equal to `dig`. In fact, I don't understand the role of `dig` at all.

Comment: I don't know Ruby, but my guess would be that it's calculating the zeros needed for left-padding the value to a length that is 8 digits (e.g., `10001` to `00010001` so that the inverted value is correct (`10001000`).

Answer (score 1):

When str is "47", binary will be assigned "111101".

```
  binary = str.to_i.to_s(2).reverse
```

Normally, you represent binary values as 8 characters or 8 bits. At this point, you can't simply convert your binary string back to an integer. "111101" is 61 in binary.

Instead, you need to pad "111101" with zeroes until it has 8 bits. That's what the following code does.

```
  dig += 8 until dig >= binary.length
  binary += '0' until binary.length == dig
```

Once you have 8 bits, you can convert it back to an integer.